# java.lang.reflection.InvocationTargetException during creation of object

Tags: junit, playframework

I have difficult to figure out to create an object in a class for jUnit test.
In my test I have : `User user = new User();` , and I receive a

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException cathed into

```
public abstract class ReflectiveCallable {
    public Object run() throws Throwable {
        try {
            return runReflectiveCall();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw e.getTargetException();
        }
    }
```

This is my User class:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private Double internalKey = (new Random()).nextDouble();

  protected User() {
    super();
}

  public User(String firstName, String lastName) {
  super();    
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  }


  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }

  public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
  }

  public String getInternalKey() {
    return internalKey;
  }

}
```

What is wrong? thanks

Comment: Please include the complete error message and stack trace, and the code from the test that is failing.

Comment: Seems that the mistake came from the field "internalKey". When I execute jUnit I receive  java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError that point to this field

Comment: The ExceptionInInitializerError should also show a root cause. In Java, there are often chains of multiple exceptions, with each one triggered by an underlying cause. It's important to post the entire error trace to Stack Overflow if you want to get the best assistance.